# Is it legal for a car to have a paper license plate in California?

Tags: california, license-plates

For over a year a car I see most days has a rear license plate that only has *XXX Chevrolet*. The license plate frame says *XXX Chevrolet.com*. Is there an exemption that allows the vehicle owner to use this in place of a standard USA license plate?

Answer (score 4):

[California Vehicle Code section 4456 (c), operative until January 1, 2019:](http://codes.findlaw.com/ca/vehicle-code/veh-sect-4456.html)

> (c) A vehicle displaying a copy of the report of sale may be operated without license plates or registration card until either of the following, whichever occurs first:
>
> (1) The license plates and registration card are received by the purchaser.
>
> (2) A 90-day period, commencing with the date of sale of the vehicle, has expired.

The car is not required to have license plates right after it is purchased.  Most dealers will put a sign with their name and/or logo in place of the license plate.

If the car has been without permanent plates for more than 90 days, and it hasn't been sold again, then it is probably in violation of this law.

As of January 1, 2019, the law will [change](http://codes.findlaw.com/ca/vehicle-code/veh-sect-4456-nr2.html), and the dealer will provide a numbered temporary plate.  This plate can only be used until the permanent plates arrive, up to a maximum of 90 days.

Comment: Steve Jobs was pretty famous for driving new cars every 90 days and never putting license plates on any of them.